# Spring boot and mongo db gitlab CI/CD

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, api, docker, gitlab

I have set up a spring boot API that does CRUD operations with MongoDB running. 
I need to run the commands on CI with hosted MongoDB automatically using GitLab

```
mvn clean install -B
```

and

```
mvn clean test
```

from .gitlab-ci.yml.

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:128) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

Looking for a .gitlab-ci.yml file that does Mongo server instantiation and DB creation before running mvn clean install

current .gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: maven:3.6-jdk-11

stages:
  - build

cache:
  paths:
    - target/

services:
  - mongo:latest

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - "mvn clean install -B"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./target/*************
```

Comment: What is the database URL that you use in your application properties? Most probably you need to change localhost to `mongo` to have it working in gitlab-ci...

Comment: I use 
`
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true
merlot.target.db.mongo.uri=mongodb://mongo:27017/<dbname>

server.port=8095
`

Comment: how about the gitlab runner? is it a docker runner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the prominent answers/ comments

I was able to solve the problem using embed.mongo in such a way that while the normal API run's it uses actual Mongo store hosted. The tests will be run on embed.mongo

Dependency added :

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <version>1.48.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Common Mongo config

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class })
public class MongoConfig {
}
```

Annotations used for the test class

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MongoConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@AutoConfigureDataMongo
```